# I install android SDK command-line Tools (latest) and still failed to run when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android-sdk-tools, flutter-doctor, android-licenses

I install android SDK command-line Tools (latest) and still failed to run when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EpdX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmYGA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcchf.png)

I install android SDK command-line Tools (latest) and still failed to run when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by run the following command in cmd.

```
flutter upgrade
```